# VSCode - how to manage multiple team projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have on premise Team Foundation Server to which we connect VSCODE. As it seems, VSCODE requires dedicated workspace per each Team Project in order to perform TFS activities such as associate to Work Item of the Team Project. Is it possible to create one workspace for all team projects included in the TFS collection, same as and just change the connection each time to another Team Project, similar to team explorer Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple projects per workspace are coming in the next version of Visual Studio Code and can already be tested in the current [Insider Build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders). See the [official announcement](https://twitter.com/_clarkio/status/905850172072235008) on Twitter.

Comment: Thank u for your reply :).

Comment: Can u pls recommend an RSS feed with helpful VSCODE updates, in addition https://code.visualstudio.com/feed.xml ? The links u kindly provided are to twitter.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. As answer to your question: I'm afraid I don't know any related feeds, only several Twitter accounts.